# Laravel 5 Paginator - Item Ranges missing (Showing x of x )

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

Im upgrading from Laravel 4 to Laravel 5 and have noticed that I can no longer call `getFrom()` or `getTo()` on the Paginator object.

I can see in the source code (`Illuminate\Pagination\Pagintor.php`) that it no longer has `protected function calculateItemRanges()` when compared to L4. Am I missing something here? How can I display ranges e.g. `Now showing x of x`now in laravel 5? Is this something that I now have to add in myself? Why has it been removed in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new methods for that are called `firstItem()` and `lastItem()`.

[In the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L229-L246):

```
/**
 * Get the number of the first item in the slice.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function firstItem()
{
    return ($this->currentPage - 1) * $this->perPage + 1;
}

/**
 * Get the number of the last item in the slice.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function lastItem()
{
    return $this->firstItem() + $this->count() - 1;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you. Strange how this isn't mentioned in the docs [http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination] anymore

Comment: These two functions() might be incorrect, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I would say firstItem() and lastItem() might be problematic **if there is no data retrieved**, given the current logic of these functions.

For example, code in the controller:

```
$users = App\User::select('id')->paginate(10);
$begin =  $users->firstItem();
$end = $users->lastItem();

return view('users/index')->with('begin',$begin)->with('end',$end);
```

code in the view:

```
<p>showing item {{$begin}} to {{$end}}</p>
```

As a result, it shows wrong information: showing item 1 to 0.

I've created an [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7986) and proposed changes in laravel/framework on this matter.

Comment: Good catch Carter, ill handle this locally and hopefully the fix will be implemented into the framework